# Is there a way in Lodash to merge duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

This is going to be a really question, but one I cannot figure out for the life of me.  I am not even sure the correct function I could use.

Consider the following:

[image]

As you can see we have an array of objects, each object has a key (the date) and a value of an array.

As we can see there are two objects with the same date. How can I merge those two objects together such that I have one date (August 10th) with an array of two objects instead of two objects with an array of one object.

I think this would be an array method (something like filter?) with a collection method?

I am not sure. **Help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Solution starts here:

var results = [];
var temps = {};

//Iterate through the dates to find uniq keys(date).
_.each(dates, function(date) {
    //Store uniq keys(date) and it's value.
    _.each(date, function(value, key) {
    if (temps.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        temps[key] = temps[key].concat(value);
    } else {
        temps[key] = value;
    }
  });
});

//Tranform the object into an array.
_.map(temps, function(value, key) {
   var item = {};
   item[key] = value;
   results.push(item);
});
//results is your answer
```